# Match only the line which end with specific char

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match the line which does not contain the final dot (full stop/period), in order to add it afterwards.

```
Someword someword someword.

Someword someword someword

Someword someword someword.
```

These are my unsuccessful attempts:

```
.+(?=\.) 
.+[^.]
```

--- update

This works for me:

```
.+\w+(?:\n)
```

https://regex101.com/r/sR0aD7/1

Comment: Is each line an own expression?

Comment: No. I have a text which has some line ending with dots, and some not. I have to add the full stop where it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
.+\w+(?:\n)
```

https://regex101.com/r/sR0aD7/1

Answer (score 2):

The following should match a string that ends with anything but dot: `[^.]$` - "anything but dot" and end-of-text marker.

Comment: This is the opposite of what was asked for.

Comment: Mr downvoter, would you mind telling me what's wrong with this answer and how I could improve it?

Answer (score 1):

> How to match the line which does not contain the final dot (full stop/period),

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
/(?!\.$)/
```

OR else you can also inverse test:

```
if (!/\.$/.test(input)) { console.log("line is not ending with dot"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression is one way i think you can use this method also --->

```
 function lastCharacter(sentence){

        var length = sentence.length;
        return sentence.charAt(length-1);
    }
```

Example :-

Input  ---> Hey JavaScript is damm good.

Use    ---> lastCharacter('Hey JavaScript is damm good.');

Output ---> '.'

In other cases you can check with if condition for dot('.').

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this: `[^\.]$`

`$` - Indicates end of line.

`[^...]` - Indicates selecting lines not containing "..."

`\.` - This is the escaped "." Character.  It needs to be escaped because `.`  is anything.

Pulling this together, you get a regular expression `.+[^\.]$` which will match your line.  You will need the `m` flag (Multiline) for this to work (I believe)

Comment: No need to escape the dot inside a character class. -> `[^.]$` (As suggested by @Sebi.)